# Can I use C++ templates to implement two classes which only differ by one field type?

Tags: c++, class, templates, subclass

I am trying to implement a `Controller` class for **two** systems. Each `Controller` uses a `Solver` class instance.

I already have **two** `Solver` class implementations:

```cpp
class AbstractSolver { virtual void func() = 0; };
class System1Solver : AbstractSolver { void func() override; };
class System2Solver : AbstractSolver { void func() override; };
```

The `Controller` implementation is the **same** for **both** `Solver` types. I *could* implement **both** `Controller` classes like...

```cpp
class System1Controller { 
  public:
    System1Controller(System1Solver solver);
    System1Solver solver;
    void func() { solver.func(); };
};

class System2Controller { 
  public:
    System2Controller(System2Solver solver);
    System2Solver solver;
    void func() { solver.func(); };
};
```

I'd like to **not** copy and paste the same code. Both `System?Controller` implementations are **identical**, except for the **type** of `solver`. Can I instead use **templates** somehow to achieve code re-use?

```cpp
template <class SolverClass>
class Controller {
  public:
    Controller(SolverClass solver);
    SolverClass solver;
    void func() { solver.func(); };
};

class System1Controller : Controller<System1Solver>;
class System2Controller : Controller<System2Solver>;
```

**Edit:** This example actually works. Thanks everyone for confirming this was an appropriate way to accomplish this.

```cpp
/* Compile with g++ -O3 -std=c++14 -o crimes metaprogramming_crimes.cpp */

#include <iostream>

class AbstractSolver { virtual void func() = 0; };
class System1Solver : AbstractSolver { public: void func() override { }; };
class System2Solver : AbstractSolver { public: void func() override { }; };

/* 
class System1Controller { 
  public:
    System1Solver solver;
    void func() { solver.func(); };
};

class System2Controller { 
  public:
    System2Controller(System2Solver solver);
    System2Solver solver;
    void func() { solver.func(); };
}; 
*/

template <class SolverClass>
class Controller {
  public:
    SolverClass solver;
    void func() { solver.func(); };
};

class System1Controller : Controller<System1Solver> { };
class System2Controller : Controller<System2Solver> { };

auto main()->int {

    System1Controller controller1;
    System2Controller controller2;

    if (typeid(controller1) != typeid(controller2)) {
        std::cout << "Yay!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Boo." << std::endl;
    }

};
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: A nitpick, you want to "achieve" code reuse, you're trying not to repeat yourself.

Comment: Why not just use `AbstractSolver` and only have one `Controller` class?

Comment: It depends on the lifetime of your solver variable.  If the Controller *needs* to take a copy of the solver then a polymorphic solution won't work.  But, it the solver will still exist when the controller needs it then it doesn't matter and a template version can work:  Here is a sample of each: https://onlinegdb.com/r1vmTTB7O

Comment: @MarkRansom this does work, actually. Thanks for the confirmation that this approach is alright.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Thanks so much for looking into those examples. The controller can only have a default constructor unfortunately, so I think metaclasses are one of the few options.

Comment: @user207421 See above comment to JerryJeremiah, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use polymorphism: keep a pointer to your `AbstractSolver` in the single `Controller` class, and pass appropriate concrete solver to the controller's constructor.

Comment: You would probably want to use a `unique_ptr` member in `Controller` to manage the lifetime of the AbstractSolver object.

Answer (score 0):

This example actually does work. Thanks everyone for confirming that metaclasses are appropriately used here.

**metaprogramming_crimes.cpp**

```cpp
/* Compile with g++ -O3 -std=c++14 -o crimes metaprogramming_crimes.cpp */

#include <iostream>

class AbstractSolver { virtual void func() = 0; };
class System1Solver : AbstractSolver { public: void func() override { }; };
class System2Solver : AbstractSolver { public: void func() override { }; };

/* 
class System1Controller { 
  public:
    System1Solver solver;
    void func() { solver.func(); };
};

class System2Controller { 
  public:
    System2Controller(System2Solver solver);
    System2Solver solver;
    void func() { solver.func(); };
}; 
*/

template <class SolverClass>
class Controller {
  public:
    SolverClass solver;
    void func() { solver.func(); };
};

class System1Controller : Controller<System1Solver> { };
class System2Controller : Controller<System2Solver> { };

auto main()->int {

    System1Controller controller1;
    System2Controller controller2;

    if (typeid(controller1) != typeid(controller2)) {
        std::cout << "Yay!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Boo." << std::endl;
    }

};
```